# How to use to make custom decorators in Django?

Tags: django, decorator, profile

I am absolutely beginners in python, django framework. I don't know how to make custom decorators in django.
I am trying to, if user's profile is 100% completed they can apply job,  else they can shows the warning message "your profile is nit completed, please first of all complete your profile then apply this job"

I have following this code
models.py

```
class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    random = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} profile'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('jobseeker:profile_count')



    @property 
    def percentage_complete(self):
        percent = { 'random': 50, 'image': 50}
        total = 0
        if self.random:
            total += percent.get('random', 0)
        if self.image:
            total += percent.get('image', 0)
        return total
```

decorators.py

```
def complete_profile_required(view_func):
def wrapper_func(request, *args, **Kwargs):
    if request.user.profile.percentage_complete == 100:
        print(request.user.profile.percentage_complete)
        return redirect('jobseeker:apply_job')
    else:
        return view_func(request, *args, **Kwargs)
return wrapper_func
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@jobseeker_required
@complete_profile_required
def apply_job(request):
    return render(request, 'apply_job.html')
```

urls.py

```
 path('apply_job', views.apply_job, name='apply_job')
```

[it will returns the this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VATy5.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to redirect to another view. You are getting the `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. Because you are redirecting it the same view.

You have to change your decorator

```
def complete_profile_required(view_func):
  def wrapper_func(request, *args, **Kwargs):
    if request.user.profile.percentage_complete == 100:
        # change your logic here
        return redirect('jobseeker:another_view')
    else:
        return view_func(request, *args, **Kwargs)
return wrapper_func
```